# How does karp reduction work?

Tags: algorithms

I understand karp reduction can be used to change a problem and calls an oracle. But what is the oracle? How is it used? What are the details of a karp reduction? What is it that is reduced? I found the material to read about it somewhat inaccessible.

Comment: I think your question will be better served if you ask something more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs473/sp2011/Lectures/21_notes.pdf) material, there 'instance' means input word, I guess.

This is *the* main method to prove complexity problems. For example, the [Hamilton cycle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton_path_problem) is **NP-complete**, meaning that 'if there is an oracle for Positive Answer', then the answer is 'verified' in polynomial time (of the size of the input). Now the input is a $G$ graph, and the oracle can be the Hamilton cycle itself. It is also NP-*complete*, meaning that any other NP problem can be reducted to this Hamilton cycle problem.

See also [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems), all problems reducted one to the other.